# Add Operation with numbers

Tags: javascript, concatenation, addition

I wrote this code as part of a calculator, for practice. It mostly works as intended.

However, the add operation concatenates the two numbers instead of adding them. Why?

```
function calcApp (aNumber, bNumber) {
    var a = prompt("Enter A number :");
    var b = prompt("Enter B number :");
    var mathSign = prompt("Enter Math Sign :");

    aNumber = a;
    bNumber = b;

    if (mathSign == "+") {
        alert(a + b);
    }
    else if (mathSign == "-") {
        alert(a - b);
    }
    else if (mathSign == "*") {
        alert(a * b);
    }
    else if (mathSign == "/") {
        alert(a / b);
    }
    else {
        prompt("Enter a valid Math sign!!")
    }
}
calcApp();
```

Comment: parse them to integer. pareseInt

Comment: The variable `aNumber` and `bNumber` defined is not used.

Comment: Most likely because they aren't numbers but strings?

Answer (score 4):

`prompt` returns a string. When you use the `+` operator on strings, they are concatenated.

You have to get the number value of the user's input. You can do that in a variety of different ways:

```js
var str = '5.4';

console.log(parseInt(str, 10)); // parse integer from decimal numeric string
console.log(parseFloat(str));
console.log(+str);
console.log(Number(str));
```

Comment: please add radix to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), becuase of the assumed octal numbers with leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` will returns a string. You need to convert it to number.

You can use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object to convert string to number.

If you are using `Number` object then check for [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (Not-A-Number). For Example, `Number('55 abc')` returns `NaN`

Careful when use `parseInt` which will strip decimal numbers. For Example, parseInt('12.99') returns `12`.

Here's your code updated with `Number` object,

```
function calcApp (aNumber, bNumber) {
    var a = prompt("Enter A number :");
    var b = prompt("Enter B number :");
    var mathSign = prompt("Enter Math Sign :");

    aNumber = a;
    bNumber = b;

    //Convert to number
    a = Number(a); <----------
    b = Number(b); <----------

    if (mathSign == "+") {
        alert(a + b);
    }
    else if (mathSign == "-") {
        alert(a - b);
    }
    else if (mathSign == "*") {
        alert(a * b);
    }
    else if (mathSign == "/") {
        alert(a / b);
    }
    else {
        prompt("Enter a valid Math sign!!")
    }
}
calcApp();
```